# Defining LESS media queries within selectors

Tags: css, less, media-queries

Are there any issues (performance is my primary concern) if instead of defining CSS selectors within media queries (example 1), you define media queries within CSS selectors (example 2).

#Example 1 - CSS selectors within media queries

```
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .foo { ... }
  .bar { ... }
  .hello { ... }
  .world{ ... }
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .foo { ... }
  .bar { ... }
  .hello { ... }
  .world{ ... }
}

@media (min-width: 1500px) {
  .foo { ... }
  .bar { ... }
  .hello { ... }
  .world{ ... }
}
```

#Example 2 - media queries within CSS selectors

```
.foo {
  @media (min-width: 600px) { ... }
  @media (min-width: 1000px) { ... }
  @media (min-width: 1500px) { ... }
}

.bar {
  @media (min-width: 600px) { ... }
  @media (min-width: 1000px) { ... }
  @media (min-width: 1500px) { ... }
}

.hello {
  @media (min-width: 600px) { ... }
  @media (min-width: 1000px) { ... }
  @media (min-width: 1500px) { ... }
}

.world{
  @media (min-width: 600px) { ... }
  @media (min-width: 1000px) { ... }
  @media (min-width: 1500px) { ... }
}
```

You may be wondering "why do this?". There are some limitations in LESS around extending classes across inside media queries, and also scoping variables.

Comment: Performance difference in terms of LESS compilation or browser rendering? The latter depends on how the CSS is generated, since style rules may appear in `@media` rules but **not** the other way around.

Comment: How may the second example work? By "selectors", do you mean [mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature)? Called outside any rule, these mixins should work but the occurence written in your question doesn't afaik. You should add parentheses like `.foo() { @media {} @media{} @media{} }` so this occurence isn't output as (invalid) CSS but just defined as a mixin and then you can call this mixin and it will output 3 media at-rules with rules in each of them

Comment: In my tests it looks like this way of defining media queries is not supported.

Comment: Using this traditional support doesn't seem to work when using an ID selector in Firefox:  @media (min-width: 1500px) {
  #foo { ... }
}

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Short answer, no. There are no performance issues in defining media queries within CSS selectors.

But let's dive in...

As described in Anselm Hannemann great article [Web Performance: One or Thousands of Media Queries](https://helloanselm.com/writings/web-performance-one-or-thousand-media-queries) there is no performance loss from adding the media queries in the manner you are.

As long as the same set of media queries are being used in each selector there is no major performance hit other than your CSS file might be a bit larger.

```
.foo {
  @media (min-width: 600px) { ... }
  @media (min-width: 1000px) { ... }
  @media (min-width: 1500px) { ... }
}

.bar {
  @media (min-width: 600px) { ... }
  @media (min-width: 1000px) { ... }
  @media (min-width: 1500px) { ... }
}
```

However, it **does** matter how many *different* media queries you use. Different being different `min-widths`, `max-widths` and so on.

Answer (score 7):

The issue is it doesn't work!  Things may have changed over the years. I tried putting media queries inside the selectors, at least Firefox complains its an invalid property name.

Here's what [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) says:

> The @media at-rule may be placed at the top level of your code or
> nested inside any other conditional group at-rule.

It can only be nested inside another *conditional group at-rule*.

Comment: I can't get it to work either. Can you give an example of what, "It can only be nested inside another conditional group at-rule." means?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts for exemple `@media screen{}` so its not avalaible for print, it can also be `@supports` but not inside a selector : `selector {}` . this is what it means ;) *(if that helped)*

Comment: Confirmed in June 2022, I cannot nest media query `@media` at-rule inside a `type` or `class` selector.

Comment: This question is for LESS that compiles it to standard CSS. Standard CSS without compilation does not yet support this

Answer (score 4):

There shouldn't be a performance difference looking at the way browsers handle media queries. Browser engines do serialize and strip out duplicated media-queries so they only need to evaluate each media query once. Also they cache the queries so that they can re-use it later on. It doesn’t matter if you use one big or multiple media-queries in your code assuming your values are mostly the same.

---

Some of the possibilities when there can be performance issues

- You use multiple media queries with different values and the browser window is re-sized. As the browser window is re-sized, multiple media queries can be a big overhead on the cpu.
- When the CSS selectors are too complex. A complex CSS selector is much performance hindering than multiple media queries. So having multiple media queries inside complex selectors can cause performance issues