# SCSS - Adding & between a class and the {

Tags: sass

I understand this:

```
.items {
    @media $desktop {
      color: red;
    }
  }
```

But what does this mean? Can some one please explains what the **&** after **.items--open** means?

```
.items--open & {
   @media $desktop {
     color: red;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/) article could explain to you everything you need to know about the `&` of SASS.

Simple explanation (from the article):

> We can think of the & as a mechanism that allows us to place the parent selector wherever we need it in our child selector. It allows us to nest with alterations. Let's look at some more examples.

Basically is a utility that allows you to better control the placement of parent selectors in SCSS classes.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax/use of ampersand(&) is to **place the parent selector with child**
For example (if you need below css)

```
.items--open.some-class{
 color: red;
}

.items--open.some-2-class{
 color: white;
}
..so on so forth
```

you have to use below code

```
.items--open {
 &.some-class{
     color: red;
 }
 &.some-2-class{
     color: white;
 }
}
```

There are plenty of mistakes in your code.

Wrong

```
.items {
 @media $desktop {
  color: red;
 }
}
.items--open & {
   @media $desktop {
     color: red;
   }
```

Right

```
.items {
    @media #{$desktop} { //wrap variable in ${}
        color: red;
    }
}

.items--open {
    &.item { //You can't use @media with (&) here, it should be selector
        color: red;
    }
}

.item--open {
    &@media (min-width: 1200px) { // you can't do this
        color: red;
    }
}

.item--open {
    @media (min-width: 1200px) { // you can do this
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Im not sure this answer is correct. [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28871612/defining-css-media-queries-within-selectors/28872072),might help for the media query part, and take a look at the link in Alberto's answer for the use of `&` specifically [this part](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/#article-header-id-5)

Comment: @DavidT Sorry about that, Updated the answer :)