# Is there a way to define a media query inside of an existing selector?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to define a media query inside of an existing selector? Also, it looks like browsers **don't** support it.

Something like:

```
.myClass {
    background-color: gray;

    @media (min-width: 600px) {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

That gives an error:

[image]

This is similar to this question but my question is asking if it's not supported at this time:

[Defining CSS media queries within selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28871612/defining-css-media-queries-within-selectors)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Defining CSS media queries within selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28871612/defining-css-media-queries-within-selectors)

Comment: @RandomCOSMOS It sort of does but in my tests in Firefox it is giving errors using the code above. Someone said that it's not supported.

Comment: *it looks like browsers don't support it.* --> where did you read about such syntax? because it doesn't exist in CSS

Comment: @TemaniAfif I didn't read about it before. I thought, I wonder if this would work. Then I read the post linked to by RandomCosmos. And that post mentions it as if it works.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts that post is talking about LESS not CSS.

Comment: @TemaniAfif that might be why I never saw it before. So it's not possible in regular CSS. Do you want to put it in an answer?

Answer (score 2):

```css
.myClass {
    background-color: gray;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
    .myClass{
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Consider Trying Something Like This,

Also if you want to just have this in your code you can use SASS - ext: style.scss
And insert this code in the scss file also don't forget to link the css file

```css
.myClass {
    background-color: gray;

    @media (min-width: 600px) {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```