# How to remove the space between these two flex items when resizing

Tags: html, css

I need some help with my code. Right now, this is what it looks like:

[image]

I need it to look like this:

[image]

You can see all of the media queries I tried on the css block as comments in the end of the css.  If possible, let me know what I did wrong and how to achiieve the ideal look. Thanks in advance.

```css
#wrap {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  @media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}


/*LAYOUT**/

.cont {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cont section {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.cont .left {
  /* flex-basis: 50%; */
  float: left;
  left: 0;
  padding: 4rem;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  /* 20211129_수정 */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cont .right {
  float: right;
  right: 0;
  /* flex-basis: 50%; */
  padding: 4rem;
  box-shadow: -1.52vh 0 3.8vh -.95vh rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* .cont .topbox{
    height: 30rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;

} */

@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
  .cont {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
  }
  .cont section {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .cont .left,
  .cont .right {
    transform: scale(0.6);
    resize: both;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}


/* @media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
    #wrap {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .cont {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: auto;
    }

    .cont section {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .cont .left{
        width: 100%;
    }
    .cont .right {
        position: inline-block;
        justify-content: center;
    }
} */


/* @media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
    .cont {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        height: auto;
        justify-content: center;
        position: fixed;
    }
    
    .cont .left,
    .cont .right {
        width: 100%;
        transform: scale(0.6);

    }
} */


/* @media (max-width: 1300px) {
    .cont {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        height: auto;
    }

    .cont .left, .cont .right {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .cont .left {
        padding-right: 0;
    }

    .cont .right {
        padding-left: 0;
    }
} */


/* @media (max-width: 1300px) {
    .cont {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
    }
    .cont section {
        height: auto;
    }
    .cont .left,
    .cont .right {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        transform: scale(0.8);
        justify-content: center;

    }
} */


/* @media (max-width: 1300px) {

        .cont section{
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            
    }
        .cont .left,
        .cont .right {
            width: 100%;
            float: none;
            display: inline-flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;

        }
    } */


/* @media (max-width: 1300px) {
        .cont section {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
        .cont .left,
        .cont .right {
            width: 100%;
            float: none;
            display: inline-block;
        }
    } */
```

```html
<div id="wrap" class="index" style="display:flex">
  <div class="cont">
    <section class="topbox">
      <br>
      <br>
    </section>
    <section class="left">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="tbl_row">
          <p class="day">2019. 6. 10. MON</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tbl_row">
          <h1 class="name">더센터오브필라테스 부산서면점</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="tbl_row">
          <div class="shop_logo">
            <div class="logo">
              <img src="../img/sample_logo.png" alt="">
              <!-- 샘플이미지 -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="powered_area">
          <p class="powered">Powered By <img src="../img/logo02.png" alt="FIT TO BE"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- 키패드 -->
    <section class="right">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="pw">
          <!-- input 번호 4자리 입력 후 class="open" 추가 -->
          <input type="number" class="input_style" placeholder="휴대전화 번호 뒷자리 4자리">
        </div>
        <ul class="keypad clearfix">
          <li onClick=""><span class="num">1</span></li>
          <li onClick=""><span class="num">2</span></li>
          <li onClick=""><span class="num">3</span></li>
          <li onClick=""><span class="num">4</span></li>
          <li onClick=""><span class="num">5</span></li>
          <li onClick=""><span class="num">6</span></li>
          <li onClick=""><span class="num">7</span></li>
          <li onClick=""><span class="num">8</span></li>
          <li onClick=""><span class="num">9</span></li>
          <li onClick="">
            <div class="num btn_back"><span class="blind">back</span></div>
          </li>
          <li onClick=""><span class="num">0</span></li>
          <li onClick=""><span class="num btn_ok">OK</span></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="topbox">
      <br>
      <br>
    </section>
    <!-- //키패드 -->
  </div>
```

Comment: try reducing `padding` in `.cont .left`, also why there are empty `topbox` ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to remove 'paddings' on your code. It will make the divs touch eachother.

```css
#wrap {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  @media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}


/*LAYOUT**/

.cont {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cont section {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.cont .left {
  /* flex-basis: 50%; */
  float: left;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  /* 20211129_수정 */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cont .right {
  float: right;
  right: 0;
  /* flex-basis: 50%; */
  box-shadow: -1.52vh 0 3.8vh -.95vh rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* .cont .topbox{
    height: 30rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;

} */

@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
  .cont {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
  }
  .cont section {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .cont .left,
  .cont .right {
    transform: scale(0.6);
    resize: both;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}


/* @media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
    #wrap {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .cont {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: auto;
    }

    .cont section {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .cont .left{
        width: 100%;
    }
    .cont .right {
        position: inline-block;
        justify-content: center;
    }
} */


/* @media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
    .cont {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        height: auto;
        justify-content: center;
        position: fixed;
    }
    
    .cont .left,
    .cont .right {
        width: 100%;
        transform: scale(0.6);

    }
} */


/* @media (max-width: 1300px) {
    .cont {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        height: auto;
    }

    .cont .left, .cont .right {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .cont .left {
        padding-right: 0;
    }

    .cont .right {
        padding-left: 0;
    }
} */


/* @media (max-width: 1300px) {
    .cont {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
    }
    .cont section {
        height: auto;
    }
    .cont .left,
    .cont .right {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        transform: scale(0.8);
        justify-content: center;

    }
} */


/* @media (max-width: 1300px) {

        .cont section{
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            
    }
        .cont .left,
        .cont .right {
            width: 100%;
            float: none;
            display: inline-flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;

        }
    } */


/* @media (max-width: 1300px) {
        .cont section {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
        .cont .left,
        .cont .right {
            width: 100%;
            float: none;
            display: inline-block;
        }
    } */
```

```html
<div id="wrap" class="index" style="display:flex">
  <div class="cont">
    <section class="topbox">
      <br>
      <br>
    </section>
    <section class="left">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="tbl_row">
          <p class="day">2019. 6. 10. MON</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tbl_row">
          <h1 class="name">더센터오브필라테스 부산서면점</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="tbl_row">
          <div class="shop_logo">
            <div class="logo">
              <img src="../img/sample_logo.png" alt="">
              <!-- 샘플이미지 -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="powered_area">
          <p class="powered">Powered By <img src="../img/logo02.png" alt="FIT TO BE"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- 키패드 -->
    <section class="right">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="pw">
          <!-- input 번호 4자리 입력 후 class="open" 추가 -->
          <input type="number" class="input_style" placeholder="휴대전화 번호 뒷자리 4자리">
        </div>
        <ul class="keypad clearfix">
          <li onClick=""><span class="num">1</span></li>
          <li onClick=""><span class="num">2</span></li>
          <li onClick=""><span class="num">3</span></li>
          <li onClick=""><span class="num">4</span></li>
          <li onClick=""><span class="num">5</span></li>
          <li onClick=""><span class="num">6</span></li>
          <li onClick=""><span class="num">7</span></li>
          <li onClick=""><span class="num">8</span></li>
          <li onClick=""><span class="num">9</span></li>
          <li onClick="">
            <div class="num btn_back"><span class="blind">back</span></div>
          </li>
          <li onClick=""><span class="num">0</span></li>
          <li onClick=""><span class="num btn_ok">OK</span></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="topbox">
      <br>
      <br>
    </section>
    <!-- //키패드 -->
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

try giving margin from top as 50% to make it center

```
#wrap {
  margin : 50% auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color:black;
  justify-content: center;
  @media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}
```

Comment: The question was not how to move an element in the center.

Comment: I actually found that a bit helpful. But I can't upvote cause I'm a new user. So, thank you.

Comment: It's great to hear this helped you in some way

Comment: It appears to be safer to have selectors inside media queries than the other way round: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63715291/7451109